# How to automatically send an email to multiple people?

Tags: web-services, email, gmail

Say I've an email id xxx@gmail.com and I get a new mail, I want to send that new mail received instantly to multiple people say yyy@gmail.com , zzz@gmail.com, etc. Is there any script or something that I could use?

Comment: Please add a tag to your question to show what programming language you are using. Also, please edit the question to show what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://techietalkz.com/2011/12/07/how-to-auto-forward-incoming-emails-in-gmail-to-multiple-recipients/

and

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50372/auto-forwarding-emails-to-2-email-addresses

I think you'll need to login to the forwarding e-mail addresses in order to verify you're not just sending out unwanted spam, though.